# simple SRTP for method and property

Tags: f#

I can't remember how to get SRTPs to work any more

I want a function that takes a param and calls a specified method, easy?

```
let inline YearDuck< ^a when ^a : (member Year : Unit -> string)>  (x : ^a) : string = 
    x.Year ()
```

but I get this

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0072  Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
```

it knows x is an ^a, I've specified ^a has method Year, so whats the problem?

(actually I want Year to be a property, but I thought i would walk before running)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way instead:

```ml
let inline YearDuck x =
    (^a : (member Year : unit -> string) x)
```

Test code:

```ml
open System

type YearTest (dt : DateTime) =
    member _.Year() = string dt.Year

YearTest(DateTime.Now)
    |> YearDuck
    |> printfn "%A"   // "2022"
```

I wish I could say why it works this way and not the way you tried, but I really don't know, and I don't think it's clearly documented anywhere. SRTP is just dark magic in its current form.

If you want a property instead, try this:

```ml
let inline YearDuck x =
    (^a : (member get_Year : unit -> string) x)

type YearTest (dt : DateTime) =
    member _.Year = string dt.Year

YearTest(DateTime.Now)
    |> YearDuck
    |> printfn "%A"   // "2022"
```

Comment: cool, I do SRTPs about once every 2 years and everytime I struggle

Comment: I'm amazed (and relieved) to see it works with ephemeral types in type providers

Comment: They already have IR in work to make SRTP methods invocation with a simple dot notation like you tried, but currently we have to use this ugly and verbose syntax. Hope the normal invocation will be delivered soon